# Specifying Options when using Map abbreviated form ("/@")

Tags: function-construction, map

I want to make /@ with some option, Like PlotRange->All

```
    f={{{2, 12, 21, 139, 130, 138, 128, 18, 11, 1}}, {{0, 8, 24, 126, 152, 
   132, 120, 24, 8, 1}}, {{3, 4, 12, 60, 142, 291, 68, 12, 2, 
   3}}, {{1, 4, 14, 83, 173, 209, 94, 13, 6, 1}}, {{10, 21, 46, 125, 
   95, 102, 107, 40, 22, 15}}, {{9, 24, 31, 95, 113, 150, 105, 26, 24,
    6}}, {{3, 4, 15, 96, 138, 231, 90, 10, 10, 0}}, {{23, 49, 38, 86, 
   43, 32, 60, 37, 41, 33}}};
Show[ListLinePlot /@ f]
```

[image]

I would like to change the plot Range, or give some plot legends. Is there a way I can do it all by one command?

Comment: Something like `ListLinePlot[#,Range->100]& /@ f`?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, :-) I don't think `Range` is a recognized option

Comment: @JasonB  There's something **like** it, though.  :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```
Show[ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> All] & /@ f]
```

but the `PlotRange` of the final plot is still controlled by the first argument to `Show`.  This works,

```
Show[ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> MinMax@f] & /@ f]
```

[image]

But as Chip Hurst points out, the smart way to get the same plot is `Show[ListLinePlot /@ f, PlotRange -> All]`

In this case, I think you get a better plot via

```
ListLinePlot[Flatten[f, 1], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it is really helpful!

Comment: @JasonB For your first two solutions, why not place `PlotRange` inside `Show`? `Show[ListLinePlot /@ f, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @ChipHurst, um, because [I am not a smart man](http://i.imgur.com/uQoHgUV.png)

Comment: Perhaps use `With[{minmax = MinMax@f}, ...]` so that you're not recomputing the min-max each time (depending on what `f` is, it could be non-trivial)